# How do I replace cell values of a raster using values of another raster with differing extent?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, raster-calculator

I have two rasters (raster1 and raster2). The raster1 extent is smaller than raster2. I want to replace the value of raster2 pixels using raster1 pixels. How can I replace the values?

Answer (score 1):

Is it acceptable for you to use GDAL? If it is then you can do what you want with gdalwarp http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html

The command to use is

```
gdalwarp raster1.tif raster2.tif
```

Command will write data from source image "raster1.tif" into target image "raster2.tif" and if the target image already exists and is of such a format that can be updated then pixels from raster1 will be written over the original pixels. Uncompressed geotiff is good for the output format. You can compress or convert the updated image afterwards if needed.

Comment: I have the same question. How can this be accomplished using only the tools native to arcgis (likely with spatial or 3d analyst)?